# Getting a value from method for a chart

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying a get a value from a method and use it for a graph but while I am trying to get a value, it is showing null.

**TS**

```
`bgs= [];

 getbgs() {
  this.bgsService.getbgss(this.token).subscribe(
  data => {
   this.bgs = data.map(k => k.bgs);
 console.log(this.bgs);   // I can get the value here      
  }
 );
 }

 public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
  { data: [this.bgs], label: 'Series A' },
console.log("chart:" + this.bgs) // here the bgs is showing null .
];`
```

Comment: I assume the console log with null came before the one with value right? That is due to async calls. The _bgs_ will only be populated when the subscription returns a value. You have to dynamically map the _bgs_ in your HTML or assign _lineChartData_ value inside subscription.

Comment: Yes null value populate before the valued one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do.

```
bgs= [];
public lineChartData: Array<any>

ngOnInit(){
    this.lineChartData = []
    . . .
}

getbgs() {
    this.bgsService.getbgss(this.token).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.bgs = data.map(k => k.bgs);    
            this.lineChartData = [
                { data: [this.bgs], label: 'Series A' }
            ]
        }
   );
}
```

Comment: This is throwing error in HTML that data is not defined

Comment: Error on the line `{ data: [this.bgs], label: 'Series A' }`?

Comment: 1<div style="display: block;">
            <canvas baseChart width="400" height="180" style="margin-left:5%;margin-top: 5%;" [datasets]="lineChartData"
              [labels]="lineChartLabels" [options]="lineChartOptions" [colors]="lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChartLegend"
              [chartType]="lineChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
          </div>`         It's showing error in **lineChartData**

Comment: I had edited _lineChartData_ into _this.lineChartData_. Try and see the error remains.

Comment: HomeComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: ng-charts configuration error I m getting this. Basically in html showing error in  **[datasets]="lineChartData"**

Comment: Was this error present before? Seems like wrong configuration or invalid data.

Comment: as lineChartData is inside a method It could get it

Comment: That's not the problem. Are you sure the configurations are correct? Did you try with a sample data? Which package are you using for graphs?

Comment: @Chris Please show the sample data and the value in _bgs_. P.S. Can you provide a stackblitz demo?

Comment: It's working. Actually we have to handle null value for ng2-chart. Thank you for your inputs. Helped a lot!!

Comment: That's why i initialized _lineChartData_ in ngOnInit(). Anyways happy to help!

Comment: will be in touch tq